# PHP - Contact Form with Attachment Submission - file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer, contacts

I've been making a contact form that has an attachment option, but when I tried it, I got this message

> "Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in
>    sample-name.php on line 26
>
> Cannot send mail."

How can I fix this?

Here's my HTML code:

```
<body>

    <form action="php_sendmail_upload.php" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table width="343" border="1">
            <tr>
            <td>To</td>
            <td><input name="txtTo" type="text" id="txtTo"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Subject</td>
            <td><input name="txtSubject" type="text" id="txtSubject"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td><textarea name="txtDescription" cols="30" rows="4" id="txtDescription"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Form Name</td>
            <td><input name="txtFormName" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Form Email</td>
            <td><input name="txtFormEmail" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Attachment</td>
            <td><input name="fileAttach" type="file"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
```

Here's my PHP code (php_sendmail_upload.php):

```
<?php
// $strTo = $_POST["txtTo"];
$strTo = "philip.santiago@yr.com";
$strSubject = "Email attach subject";
$strMessage = nl2br($_POST["txtDescription"]);

//*** Uniqid Session ***//
$strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$strHeader = "";
$strHeader .= "From: ".$_POST["txtFormName"]."<".$_POST["txtFormEmail"].">\nReply-To: ".$_POST["txtFormEmail"]."";

$strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";

//*** Attachment ***//
if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"] != "")
{
$strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];
// THE LINE BELOW SEEMS TO BE CAUSING THE ERROR //
$strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"])));

$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
}

$flgSend = @mail($strTo,$strSubject,null,$strHeader);  // @ = No Show Error //

if($flgSend)
{
echo "Mail send completed.";
}
else
{
echo "Cannot send mail.";
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Share you `sample-name.php` please

Comment: And why you get contents of `$_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"]` instead of `$_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"]` ?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\_philip\test-website\php_sendmail_upload.php

Comment: I just followed a guide on creating forms with attachments

Comment: do yourself a favour: throw away all that code, and replace it with either the phpMailer or SwiftMailer libraries. Your php code is wide open to multiple security vulnerabilities; some of yours are quite obvious, but honestly it's very difficult to avoid vulnerabilities when trying to use PHP's `mail()` function; there are so many ways to attack it, even when doing fairly simple stuff, let alone getting more complex with attachments. The two libraries I mentioned will solve all of this and make the code you need to write to send an email with attachments really simple.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. And I'll get back here when I managed to fix it.